Databricks Merge into - Adding a condition to insert another table
I have a Delta Table called Results,  I have a list of operations that are required to be carried out on Results in sequence.
Given list of operations: ['op_1', 'op_2', 'op_3']
op_1 modifies the value column if the ip_address column is within a certain IP range.
op_2 deletes the row column if the value column is within a certain range.
op_3 modifies the grouping based on zone column.
As part of this process, I am required to modify another teams table called operation_log that is formatted in a certain way certain columns that tracks what operations were performed on which rows.  They own this table, I cannot change this part.
The operations are performed on the delta table using a MERGE INTO statement and then afterwards the actions are tracked in operation_log
Currently I have the operation and then the log of that operation happening as two separate queries being executed.  The problem I'm facing is that when the delete happens on the results, that row is no longer accessible from the table or any created views.  So I must execute log sql first.  Which is a problem if the log executes fine but the actual deletion sql fails. I have an action being recorded if no action occurred.
I tried to combine everything into one sql statement to be executed.  The delete statement example:
MERGE INTO results
USING  _vectors
    ON results.vector_id = _vectors.vector_id
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    DELETE
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    INSERT INTO operation_log (
        vector_id,
        ip_address,
        value,
        grouping,
        zone,
        action
        )
    VALUES (
        _vectors.vector_id,
        _vectors.ip_address,
        _vectors.value,
        _vectors.grouping,
        _vectors.zone,
        "DELETE"
    )

The only thing that is unfortunately a hard requirement is having this persnickety operation_log.
According to the databricks delta documentation, I am able to have multiple match conditions but is this possible to make updates and inserts to separate tables in one query?

You could enable change data feed on the Results table, and then use that to update your log table.
The change data feed will contain row level information of all affected rows (insert, update, deletes).
To enable change data feed:
ALTER TABLE Results SET TBLPROPERTIES (delta.enableChangeDataFeed = true)

You can then read from this in batch or streaming. For example:
-- version as ints or longs e.g. changes from version 0 to 10
SELECT * FROM table_changes('Results', 0, 10)

-- timestamp as string formatted timestamps
SELECT * FROM table_changes('Results', '2021-04-21 05:45:46', '2021-05-21 12:00:00')


Parse the data as needed and update your change log table

In Delta Lake and using Databricks, the MERGE INTO statement is quite versatile but does have its limitations. One significant limitation is that within a single MERGE INTO operation, you cannot target updates to more than one table. Each MERGE INTO statement can only modify one target table, either by inserting, updating, or deleting rows. This limitation means you cannot perform a delete on one table and an insert into another table (like your operation_log) in a single MERGE INTO statement
